# How to write the date of an event that lasts a few days

Tags: american-english, dates

What is the correct way to write, in American English, that something will happen over a date range?

- The event will take place through July 1-10, 2011?
- The event will take place from July 1 to July 10, 2011?
- The event will take place starting on July 1 through July 10, 2011?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 1 no, 2 yes, 3 no.

Comment: Number 3 also sort of works though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a contending opinion, I find this perfectly fine:

> The event will take place July 1-10, 2011

I would pronounce the relevant portion "July 1st through 10th" or "July 1st through the 10th."

Comment: I like this version, it's more succinct.

Comment: I was going to offer my own version, but realized we're talking about writing the date range, in which case this is what I'd use.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer this:

> The event will take place **on** July 1 **to** July 10, 2011.
>
> The event will take place **on** July 1 **through** July 10, 2011.

The choice of the second preposition here is debatable, but I judge that both of them are correct.

However, your second example is also acceptable:

> The event will take place **from** July 1 to July 10, 2011.

Here only *to* works as the second preposition. The first and third options that you gave sound very unnatural.