# What's the correct way to format a date range, time range, and days of week in a single line?

Tags: writing, writing-style, dates

I'd like to write the date and time for an event that runs for one week. Currently I have: ​

> June 3-7, 2013, 8:30am-5:30pm; Monday-Friday

Is this stylistically acceptable? Is there a better way?

Comment: This is a matter of style. I would prefer to have the "Monday-Friday" after the dates and then the times. Also, if you're going to use a ; in one place, use it after the 2013, too.

Comment: Also, those need to be en dashes not hyphens, because they’re ranges.

Comment: It is also acceptable to write the dates in the way that they are written in England and the rest of the UK, which would be *3-7 June*.

Comment: You could dump the Monday–Friday since the dates are already specified.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting dates. It is not a question about language *per se*. Also, the answer will vary by country depending on whether the 24 hour clock is in common use, whether day No. precedes/follows month, whether year is first or last, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are required to keep that level of detail, you could write

> June 3–7 (Monday–Friday), 2013, 8:30 a.m.–5:30 p.m.
>   or
>   Monday–Friday, June 3–7, 2013, 8:30am–5:30pm daily

The Associated Press Stylebook as synopsized at a [www.wwu.edu/journalism](http://www.wwu.edu/journalism/syllabi/207labmanual.htm) webpage recommends the forms *a.m.* and *p.m.* rather than *am* and *pm*.  In my opinion,  *8:30–5:30* is an adequately unambiguous designation for *8:30 a.m.–5:30 p.m.* and I'd write things like the following, in spite of having no authorities to directly support these forms.

> M–F 8:30–5:30 daily, 3–7 June 2013
>   or
>   3–7 June 2013 (M–F 8:30–5:30)
>   or
>   3–7 June 2013 (M–F 8:30–5:30 daily)

Some useful advice and links to guides appear in  [How to write date range succinctly and unambiguously in American written English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57606) and   [How to write the date of an event that lasts a few days](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23803).

Comment: Using a 24-hour representation (0830–1730) removes the need for a.m. and p.m., and reduces the fly-speck appearance of too much punctuation.

Comment: @Fortiter:  But who uses military time besides folks in the military?

Comment: Some people call those who use a 24 hour clock Europeans.

Comment: Europeans very rarely use 24-hour designations without punctuation, though. “0830–1730” looks military in Europe, too.

Comment: How to write p.m. at the end of a sentence? "p.m.." or p.m."?

Comment: @ceving, see  [When "etc." is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8382) and  [AM/PM vs a.m./p.m. vs am/pm](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22784),

Answer (score 1):

Monday–Friday, 3-7 June 2013, 08:30–17:30

Comment: Which country's format are you referring to?