# How to write the date of an event that lasts a few days [American / British English]

Tags: american-english, british-english, dates

I saw this topic: [How to write the date of an event that lasts a few days](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23803/how-to-write-the-date-of-an-event-that-lasts-a-few-days)

But have some questions. Firstly, I would like to know how to say the same but in British English. I think that "The event will take place from July 1 to July 10, 2011" would be ok in British English too - am I right?

I found somewhere on the Internet also some other form:

"The event will take place from 1st July to 10th July 2011". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is okay in BrE. Except it's already in the past ;)

Comment: @Ronan: thank you :) How about the second sentence I found on the Internet? Is it ok both in British and American English?

Comment: mirx, your first example is more likely in American English.

Comment: Both make perfect sense. One might be more right than the other, but neither is wrong. All depends on the style guide you're following.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, dates are normally the day, then the month, then the year. Your example would normally be "The event will take place from the 1st to the 10th of July, 2011"